# FFI is a required pre-requisite for Windows or posix_spawn support in the ChildProcess gem

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, ffi, rubymine

I am executing Cucumber scripts created using Ruby Programming Language, but it throws an error related to `Child Process` which has a pre-requisites od `FFI gem`, below is the error stacktrace

```
    FFI is a required pre-requisite for Windows or posix_spawn support in the ChildProcess gem. Ensure the `ffi` gem is installed. If you believe this is an error, please file a bug at http://github.com/enkessler/childprocess/issues (ChildProcess::MissingFFIError)
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/childprocess-3.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/childprocess-3.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/childprocess-3.0.0/lib/childprocess.rb:209:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/childprocess-3.0.0/lib/childprocess.rb:209:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.6/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:20:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.6/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.6/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:20:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.6/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.11.0/lib/watir.rb:1:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.11.0/lib/watir.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object.rb:1:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
E:/e2NxtAutomation/DEVOPS/Spec/Func/features/support/env.rb:4:in `require'
E:/e2NxtAutomation/DEVOPS/Spec/Func/features/support/env.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:144:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:85:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:272:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:68:in `run!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.1/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 2
```

As per Error I have successfully installed the FFI Gem

```
gem install ffi
Fetching: ffi-1.11.3-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ffi-1.11.3-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.11.3-x64-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.11.3-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for ffi after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But still the same error occurs. my machine details
OS: Windows 7
Ruby version: 2.4.0

Suggest me some workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the version of your ruby.
The FFI gem has different versions.
Some work on ruby until version 2.2.
Sometimes you are installing the latest version of the FFI gem on an old ruby version
I recommend uninstalling the current ruby and upgrading ruby to version 2.5.7. That done, reinstall the gems and see if your automation works

Comment: i have the same problem but i have ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) which i think this the latest version.  

why is ruby so hard to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install FFI - **gem install ffi -v 1.13.1**